# Android PowerPoint remote

Tags: java, android, powerpoint

I want to write an Android remote to PowerPoint. It means we can control the slides by using phone.
Where can I start from? Give me some hints please. I've just read the Android basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think RemoteDroid will work pretty well for this purpose and it's a fairly complicated job to replicate.

http://remotedroid.net/

Answer (score 1):

what I did was:

```
I use a .NET #C Client on the Windows Side and

A Java Servlet and XMLRPC Web App running on a Tomcat ("in the middle").

And of course a Android Client as the controler
```

My C# Client creates a persistent HTTP Connection to a Servlet. And the Android App is sending short HTTP GET Requests to the TomCat, stuff like goto3 or next (the request has also a kind of a Presentation ID as parameter). The Comands from the Android Device are dispatched to the previously opened Persistent HTTP Connection from the .NET Client.

In The .NET Client I use a local installed PowerPoint as an ActiveX/OLE Control. You can do pretty much everything programatically in over c# that is possible to do "by hand". Open a .ppt(x), start the SlideShow, control the Slideshow and of course it is also possible to edit the slides content. You can find a lot of examples by googling for Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint

I pair the .NET Client with the Android Phone by using a Generated QR Code. That QR Code I show in a generated PowerPoint Slide. All Work around the QR Code (C# and Android) is done by using code from the ZXing (Zebra Crossing) Project.

You can try it out, Instructions and Downloads are [here](http://www.thomas-lankes.de/fonprompt). The App is called FonPrompt and can be found in Google Play.